# All solutions of $z^2 + (i-2)z + 3-i =0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find all solutions of $$z^2 + (i-2)z + 3-i =0$$

Now this is what I do:
$$x^2 - y^2 +2xyi +(i-2)(x+iy)+3-i =0$$
$$x^2-y^2 +2xyi + xi-y-2x-2iy+3-i=0$$
$$x^2-y^2-y-2x+3+i(2xy+x-2y-1)=0$$
Now we have two equations
$$x^2-y^2-y-2x+3=0\implies x^2-y^2-2x+3=y$$
$$2xy+x-2y-1=0$$

Which means we now take

$$2xy+x-2(x^2-y^2-2x+3)-1=0$$
$$\implies 2xy+x-2x^2+2y^2+4x-6-1=0$$

By now I have realized I am dumb, and given up.

Comment: What about solving the initial quadratic equation ?

Comment: $$z^2 + (i-2)z + 3-i =(z-1)^2+i(z-1)+2=0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use the quadratic formula?  the discriminant is 
$$(i-2)^2 - 4(3-i)=-1-4i+4-12+4i=-9=( 3i)^2$$ so the quadratic formula gives you $$z = \frac{2-i \pm 3i}2=1+i, 1-2i. $$

Comment: I was afraid to in the complex plane. Does it always work in $\Bbb C$?

Comment: the quadratic formula works in $C$ too. there is nothing to be afraid about the complex numbers. polar form is there to help you find the square roots. in this problem we lucked out, only needed to find the square root of $-9.$

Answer (score 2):

Note that 
$$2xy+x-2y-1=(x-1)(2y+1).$$

Comment: How did you see this? How can I ensure this will be possible?

Comment: @OceansBleed: $2xy+x-2y-1=x(2y+1)-(2y+1)=(x-1)(2y+1)$. To check if this is true, you can expand the RHS. (Now you have $x=1$ or $y=-\frac 12$. )

Comment: Sorry, I meant, how did you see the factorisation, just experience? How do I ensure a factorization is the right path to go? Just experience as well?

Comment: @OceansBleed: Factorization is the easiest way, so I checked first if it can be factorized to eliminate $x$ as $x(2y+1)-(2y+1)$.